# how to beep on tail -f event

Tags: linux, terminal, pipe

I want my PC to make a system beep on every tail  event

I have the following command

```
tail -f development.log | grep "something rare"
```

is there an easy way like pipeing it to somthing that beeps? like

```
tail -f development.log | grep "something rare" | beep
```

if so will the grep output still be shown?

Comment: there is a beep program with is in the default repo for debian and variants just 
    apt-get install beep
but it doesn't work with the piping this way

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just define `beep` as following:

```
beep() { read a || exit; printf "$a\007\n"; beep; }
```

Then, you can use your command:

```
tail -f development.log | grep "something rare" | beep
```

Comment: sorry but this is not working, it doesn't beep or prints anything

Comment: Although direct output of tail -f is immediate, it gets buffered as soon as it goes through a pipe. You have to wait for enough "something rare" before observing anything.

Comment: You could pass the output through `sed` or similar (between tail and grep) to with a regexp replace the `something rare` with itself many times. How many times it needs to be done depends on how much the pipe is buffered.

Comment: @David - That is a hit-and-miss approach. If you want to unbuffer the data passed via a pipe, use any of the methods described in these answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000674/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe

Comment: Going off of @nagul's suggestion, here is the invocation that worked for me: `tail -f development.log | stdbuf -oL -eL grep "something rare" | beep`

Comment: Use `read -r` to avoid clobbering backslashes, and `printf '%s\007\n' "$a"` to avoid interpreting percent-escapes in the output. I also don’t think the tail call is necessary (and I’m not sure if Bash will optimize it away) – just do `while read …; do …; done` instead.

Comment: If this isn't working for you make sure your system alert volume is turned up.  It's possible to have other volumes turned up, making you think the volume is on, but not have system alerts specifically turned up ... which is the channel the beeps will use.

Answer (score 10):

[GNU screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) has a built-in feature to beep when a given window changes: see [the relevant section of the man page](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Monitor.html#Monitor).

Headline summary:

```
$ screen
$ tail -f yourfile.log    # inside the screen session
<C-a> M    # "Window 0 (bash) is now being monitored for all activity."
```

As pointed out in comments, this will beep on *every* new log entry, not just those that match "something rare", so this doesn't do quite what the OP asked for.  Still a useful trick to know IMHO.

You can get the best of both worlds by opening two `screen` windows (`<C-a> c` to open a window, `<C-a> <C-a>` to toggle between two windows):

1. monitored, with `tail -f yourfile.log | grep 'something rare'`
2. unmonitored, with a plain `tail -f yourfile.log`

Then you can sit watching the log scroll past in window 2, and you'll get beeped from window 1 when "something rare" occurs.

`screen` is awesomely versatile - I highly recommend reading up on it.

Comment: That wouldn't beep only on "something rare", would it?

Comment: It would if all that was happening in that particular window is `tail -f yourfile.log | grep something\ rare` rather than just the `tail -f logfile`

Comment: Oops, I didn't notice that he only wanted a beep on `something rare`.  Edited to reflect this.
The grep would work, but then he wouldn't see the rest of the log, only the rare lines - as I understand it he wants to be able to watch the whole log scrolling past, but be alerted on specific events.

Answer (score 3):

You could use sed to add the control-G as follows:

```
tail -f myFile | sed "s/.*/&\x07/"
```

or just on rare lines, without using grep, as follows:

```
tail -f myFile | sed -n "/something rare/s/.*/&\x07/p"
```

which says: on the lines where something rare occurs, **s**ubstitute everything for the same stuff with control-G tacked on the end, and print (but don't print the non-matching lines). Works great!

Comment: the only one that worked for me, no issues with buffering, no self-abort.  kudos for a simple OOB solution with no dependencies

Answer (score 2):

You can stop the output from being buffered in the grep command.
See man grep for details.

You can pipe the grep output into beep.

The following example is from man beep...

```
   As part of a log-watching pipeline

          tail -f /var/log/xferlog | grep --line-buffered passwd | \
          beep -f 1000 -r 5 -s
```

There's a lot of good stuff in those manuals.  If only we didn't have to read them to find it.    ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Hm, tricky. We could perhaps do something like this?

```
for i in `find | grep 7171`; do beep; echo $i; done
```

Or in your case

```
for i in `tail -f development.log | grep "something rare"`; do beep; echo $i; done
```

It seems to be doing some buffering though. I'll look if there's a way to turn off this buffering by the `for` loop.

Apparently, you should be able to adjust pipe's buffering by using `ulimit -p` but that keeps complaining about Invalid argument to me. I've also found a post that claims you need to recompile kernel to change this limit.

Answer (score 1):

The watch command has an --beep option, and you can set the polling interval as well, but the standard with 2 sec should be ok

```
watch --beep 'tail development.log | grep "something rare"'
```

Comment: Note, `watch` works by running your parameter/command every (interval) sections then coming the results to the previous run. Thus you'll want to use the normal version of the tail command, instead of using `tail -f`

Comment: This didn't work for me (despite adding `watch --beep` and wrapping my tail/grep, I still didn't get a beep).

Answer (score 0):

In a previous job, I couldn't get a reliable watcher with just command-fu, so I had a wrapper script like the one below, which inspected the file every *poll_duration* seconds and grepped the new lines for the interested phrase.

```
#!/bin/bash

file=$1
phrase=$2
poll_duration=$3

typeset -i checked_linecount
typeset -i new_linecount
typeset -i new_lines
let checked_linecount=new_linecount=new_lines=0
echo "Watching file $file for phrase \"$phrase\" every $poll_duration seconds"

while [ 1 ]
do
        let new_linecount=`wc -l $file| awk '{print $1}'`
        if [[ $new_linecount > $checked_linecount ]]; then
                let "new_lines = $new_linecount-$checked_linecount"
                head --lines=$new_linecount "$file" | tail --lines=$new_lines | grep "$phrase" && beep
                let checked_linecount=$new_linecount
        fi
        sleep $poll_duration
done
```

This was on a Unix machine. On Linux, you can go one better by using its **inotify** filewatcher interface. If this package (**inotify-tools** on Ubuntu) is present, replace

```
sleep $poll_duration
```

with

```
inotifywait -e modify "$file"  1>/dev/null 2>&1
```

This call blocks till the file is modified. *The blocking version is almost as efficient as what you'd get with the `tail -f` version if pipe could be configured to work without buffering.*

**Note:** The script first does a `head --lines=$new_linecount` to ensure that lines added to the file after we checked it do not skew the chunk of the file that gets checked in this loop.