# Using regular expressions and tail to execute a command

Tags: linux, command-line, regex, tcsh

Similar to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/37144/how-to-beep-on-tail-f-event), in Linux tcsh I want to tail a log file and when I match a regular expression I want to execute an arbitrary command.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the poster's note a comment in that question leads to an SO post on [disabling the auto-buffering when using pipes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000674/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe).  The solution was to use **unbuffer** (from [expect](http://expect.nist.gov/)), as in:

```
$ unbuffer tail -f foo | find-and-run "findwhat" "runwhat"
```

wfaulk's answer (plus ayrnieu's cleanup) provides us with the script find-and-run:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# run: find-and-run "regex-to-find" "commandtorun"
die "usage: $0 <regex> <exec-this> [exec-this-arg1 ...]\n"
   unless @ARGV >= 2;

my ($re, @run) = @ARGV; 

while (<>) {
        last if /$re/;
}
exec { $run[0] } @run;
```

Note 1: on Debian lenny, you'll need to install the "expect-dev" package; unbuffer is installed as "expect_unbuffer".

Note 2: this is completely untested and <strike>completely</strike> slightly naive.  for security, don't use this.  if you do use this, you probably want to single-quote your regex to avoid shell substitution/expansion.

Note 3: big thanks to ayrnieu for script completion and cleanup.

Comment: die "usage: regex exec-this [arg1 ...]\n" unless @ARGV >= 2; my ($re, @run) = @ARGV; ... last if /$re/; ... exec { $run[0] } @run

Comment: exec/system is not so important, but $1 $2 as is will definitely fail, and usage: is just a good idea.

Comment: better: "usage: $0 <regex> <exec-this> [<arg1> ... <argn>]\n"

Answer (score 3):

This seems suited to a short perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

while (<>) {
        last if /regex/;
}
system("ls");
```

If you want to provide a pattern and a command with as flagged arguments, see the documentation at `perldoc Getopt::Std`.

Comment: I really wanted "<> until /regex/;" to work, but I couldn't make it happen.

Comment: perl -Mwarnings -e 'scalar <> until /a/'  -- note the warning.

Answer (score 1):

In my case (on RHEL, I wanted `tail -n 0 -f file | grep -m 1 pattern` to terminate immediately when pattern occurs in the growing file), plain usage of the **unbuffer** utility from the Expect package didn't solve the problem for some reason.

But based on a blog post (http://www.smop.co.uk/blog/index.php/2006/06/26/tail-f-and-awk/) I've  discovered that redirecting input from tail launched in a subshell did the trick:

```
grep -m 1 pattern <(tail -n 0 -f file)
```

This was not as simple, though. While working in an interactive shell, the same command, when run remotely using SSH, still froze as usual:

```
ssh login@hostname 'grep -m 1 pattern <(tail -n 0 -f file)'
```

I've discovered that in this case, one must unbuffer tail's output using the **unbuffer** utility from Expect:

```
ssh login@hostname 'grep -m 1 pattern <(unbuffer -p tail -n 0 -f file)'
```

This **must not** be used on an interactive shell - unbuffer will cause an `ioctl(raw): I/O error`!

So the advice for you is that if the proposed solutions don't work, try launching `tail -f` in a subshell and if you want to do it in a script or on a non-interactive shell, using `unbuffer` or `unbuffer -p` might be required.

BTW, see this article for thorough explanation of the output buffering problem: http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/stdio_buffering/

Answer (score 0):

A different approach is to use a program like [swatch](http://sourceforge.net/projects/swatch/).  Swatch is built to do exactly what you are talking about, plus a dozen other things.